# What is the difference between using SUM or SUMX when calculating the average by sum of customer sales?

Tags: powerbi, dax

What is the difference between using SUM or SUMX when calculating the average by sum of customer sales (example 1 and example 2)? And what happens when we wrap them with calculate (example 3 and example 4)?

Example 1:

```
AverageSalesPerCustomer :=
AVERAGEX (
    Customer,
    SUM (Sales[SalesAmount])
)
```

Example 2:

```
AverageSalesPerCustomer :=
AVERAGEX (
    Customer,
    SUMX (
        Sales,
        Sales[SalesAmount]
    )
)
```

Example 3:

```
AverageSalesPerCustomer :=
AVERAGEX (
    Customer,
    CALCULATE(SUM (Sales[SalesAmount]))
)
```

Example 4:

```
AverageSalesPerCustomer :=
AVERAGEX (
    Customer,
    CALCULATE( SUMX (
        Sales,
        Sales[SalesAmount]
    ) )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

SUM function takes single column of data to add all the data in that column. Syntax:

```
SUM(<Column Name>)
```

SUMX function first iterates row by row to perform the given expression on each row and finally sum up all the values to give the final sum.
Syntax:

```
SUMX (<Table>, <Expression>)
```

Example:

> SUM(Sales[Units])

- return the sum of total units in Sales table

> SUMX(Sales, Sales[Units] * Sales[Price])

- will first multiply number of units with price for each row and then will find the sum of values found for all the rows to return total sales amount

Comment: Please note that `SUM ( 'Table'[Column] )` is strictly single-column syntax sugar for `SUMX ( 'Table' , 'Table'[Column] )`. They are evaluated identically by the engine.